# Processing: PVector and loading custom shapes

Tags: svg, vector, processing

Another Processing-related question. Could someone explain to me how PVector works within Processing? More specifically, I'm looking for a way to load a custom vector shape (.svg) but again my knowledge of Processing is too limited. So far I understand that something like this possible:

```
PVector vector1

vector1 = new PVector((width),(height));
```

Now, is it possible to also load a custom vector shape? Or am I misunderstanding vectors in relation to Processing? I would greatly appreciate if someone could provide me with some info regarding this.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PVector` class does not hold a vector shape. It holds a [mathematical vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) (in other words, a 2D or 3D point).

You're looking for [the `PShape` class](https://processing.org/reference/PShape.html), specifically [the `loadShape()` function](https://processing.org/reference/loadShape_.html) which allows you to load a `.svg` file.

```
PShape s;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  // The file "bot.svg" must be in the data folder
  // of the current sketch to load successfully
  s = loadShape("bot.svg");
}

void draw() {
  shape(s, 10, 10, 80, 80);
}
```

Comment: A follow up question: Would it be possible to get the 2D points which define a shape within a .svg file and further use them in my Processing-code?

Comment: @JohnGalt Your first stop for questions like that should always be [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/). Specifically check out the `PShape` class. It has several functions that you might use. Try something out, and if you get stuck, post an updated [mcve] in a new question, and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.